# Compute the Subtangent of the Ellipse

Tags: differential-geometry

I am self-studying Guggenheimer's "Differential Geometry". I am stuck on exercise 3 of page 13 of the book.

I am asked to compute the subtangent of the ellipse given the parametrization 
$$(x_1, x_2) = (a\cos t, b\sin t)$$

where $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$.

Now, I am told that if the ellipse is given in polar coordinates.  I.e.

$$(x_1, x_2) = (r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)$$
then the subtangent $S$ is given by

$$S = \frac{x_2 \dot{x}_1}{\dot{x}_2}$$

I've solved for $r$:

$$r = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2 \sin^{2} t + b^2 \cos^2 t}}$$

If I let $\phi = t$, then is the answer $S=a\cot t$?  This was the answer at the back of the book. I've tried the calculation several times and I can never seem to reach this. It is very long and tedious.

In a few words: How is it that $S = a\cot t$?

Comment: What is $x_1^.,x_2^.$?

Comment: I believe $x_1^{\cdot} = (r(t) \cos(t))^{\cdot}$ and $x_2^{\cdot}$ is similar. I just don't know if calculating through that route will give me $a \cot(t)$. Wolfram Alpha won't even take the formula because it is so long.

Comment: This should be typed as \dot{x}_1 ($\dot x_1$). I am not familiar with the term "subtangent," despite many years in mathematics, but I assume Guggenheimer intends what Wikipedia told me. That does agree with the formula $S=x_2\dfrac{\dot x_1}{\dot x_2}$.

Comment: I don't see what polar coordinates has to do with this. This formula for $S$ is just using the definition for any parametrization $(x_1(t),x_2(t))$. In your parametrization of the ellipse $x=(a\cos t,b\sin t)$, $t$ is *not* the polar coordinate $\phi$. But, regardless, $x_2\dfrac{\dot x_1}{\dot x_2} = -a\sin t\tan t$ is not $a\cot t$.

Comment: Ah, okay. Maybe Guggenheimer was using a different parametrization then. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If it is time derivative then get $S=\frac{-asin^2(t)}{cos(t)}=\frac{acos^2(t)-a}{cos(t)}=acos(t)-\frac{a}{cos(t)}$